# Would an ECS-specific programming language be helpful?

Tags: programming-languages, entity-component-system

I've thought about creating a programming language specifically for developing ECS, but I do not have enough experience to conclude whether or not it would be useful at all or not. Can anyone give me the broader knowledge in the field?

I have not tried anything, just an idea of a project in mind.

Comment: I think the first thing that is required to be proved or disproved, is if in general Data Oriented Design can become a real programming paradigm, e.g. Data Oriented Programming. If so, a language specialized in that paradigm would definitely be beneficial. The problem so far is that it is proved to be a solid architecture on top of other paradigms, but it is still far from being a paradigm on its own.